# How can generic type be inferred

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

The code below infers 'a' as string and 1 as number, not as type 'a', nor type 1 - i.e. it has some logic that tells it 'a' = string.

```js
let example = ['a',1]  // type inferred to (string | number)[]
example = [true,false] // correctly fails type checking
```

Given these generics:

```js
type FN<T extends unknown[]> = (...args: T)=>number|string
// infers to type FN given a function
type InferFN<T> = T extends (...args: infer A)=>number ? FN<A> : never
// infers an array of FNs given an array of functions
type InferFNArray<T extends any[]> = T extends readonly [...FNs: infer P ] ? {
  [I in keyof P] : InferFN<P[I]>
} : unknown
```

`fnArray` below infers to `(((text: string) => number) | ((value: number) => number))[]`
however it should ideally be constrained to type `FN`.
`type correctFnArrayType = InferFNArray<typeof fnArray>` shows the type is should be : `(FN<[value: number]> | FN<[text: string]>)[]`. Can fnArray be inferred to that?

```js
let fnArray = [
  (value: number)=>value,
  (text: string)=>parseInt(text,10),
]

fnArray = [ // should not fail
  (value: number)=>`${value}`,
  (text: string)=>text,
]
```

Ideally the solution would be something like:

```js
let fnArray: InferFNArray = [
  (value: number)=>value,
  (text: string)=>parseInt(text,10),
] // with type inferred to (FN<[value: number]> | FN<[text: string]>)[]
```

[code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBCAeCGC2AHUEC8EDaByWWA0AjALoQQD0ZEYAnoiBAJYB2AZiAE7sgAmVA9hAAUAZzDtmAcwgAfCEwCu8AEYcAlBiIAoGAmT10GMfJB4WsYMJAkKEAMZ9OIW2GDUIZhhaq16tgBZOANaSmpo0dBAAYgByADwAKlDQYCBM3MIQ8kyBTHwA7kwaAHxoQgB0FbDsEsIAXBDxqqhFCsoc0qLiTBKaNsxs7BkxEBIMAG6pELDuWc4MfExhPhAAkqwcMQkl6IkwKWkZghVlVTX1-RwQAIJNLYoq7BAA-FFxVyX1TCAT7L2UF4MpkwppxYG4+CxXhlRhNgbA4aDwZCWLMwPMmMIlhE1gMYldEQkkvt0kDqMVSrtkqkSVxYNwFq5MMcYnVGOtHgAFCAkF4Ab00pAwKzZEECIGoEIgHJI9RxGziHKFRCKmgAvhB6lkcvlFn93Ex8ewwWyBhkwAJBJaUsl6p1JKo0CVWg8HbJLWNzMZPvc1I65D72Kp1FobH58t9LgxIMIw-JgLwGNwQOZGSo7AtOrBmDx+N46BkAAYxAt6gvhXwOLjOSIGxHxZboOXsPEE8uSli1o3UIolmwx-JmgJ5+gMDL9uO8NP1QSbDAe4Be-1tdjKmSvWKGPa2sSSZXBvUAYXh+sNxrTAK4vHNVD8sDAT00oEgHdPbgMAqE88XzrUzS-Jg-QRrTAbcugkW5ECqSw1jAIC9kIAAGVQ8E0LRNBfRFSgwchKHHeM5D4Z8s2AQD-29ZdbgLAASXl-1VAsUNIOCbQgO1uluYCUJIUJy3TRxq07MF6wiRt2RbLtYjbZFBO7IA)

Comment: I may be missing the point, but if you want a variable to have a supertype of the inferred type, you can always just write an explicit type signature, right? I mean, going back to your first example, `["a", 1]` has type `(string | number)[]` (well, actually `[string, number]`, a subtype of the former), but in `let arr: unknown[] = ["a", 1]`, `arr` has type `unknown[]`. It's not a runtime cast; it's checked that the declared type is a supertype of the inferred one.

Comment: @Silvio Mayolo Yes one can write an explicit type signature, and that will work, however it's not DRY as the type can easily be inferred from `fnArray` - as per `InferFNArray` - rather than restating it explicitly.  The same thing typescript does in many, many other instances.

Comment: You can't really control how TS's inference works in an assignment without annotation.  You *could* use a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) helper function like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wOJAlW) instead though, so instead of `let fnArray: InferFnArray = [...]` you can write `let fnArray = inferFnArray([...])` and get the same effect.  Does that work for your needs? If so I can write up an answer; if not, what's missing?

Comment: @jcalz - thank you for that and whilst not ideal, it may be the best solution currently available.  In researching this I came across [this](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30680) by you - and thought a future solution may be to change the `as const` keyword to accept a type and then the array or object would be passed as the first generic and whatever it returned would be the final type.  e.g. `let fnArray = [...] as const InferFnArray`  would call `InferFnArray<[...]>` and use its type.

Comment: @jcalz - typescript provides a way to define generics, however it provides no equivalent to infer generic types.  The example you provided (thanks again!) - shows that one would have to repeat the array twice: once to define its type and a second time to type check it.  This is a poor solution and is probably a gap the Typescript team should consider closing.  A solution may be to enable generics to be used to infer type: `const A:InferType<*>=[...]` where the `*` denotes that the `[...]`'s default type should be passed to `InferType` as it's first arg and whatever it returns is the type.